# Symfony2 compound form, associate errors with fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an embedded form with the compound and inherit_data options set to true.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setErrorBubbling(false);

    $builder->add('date_start', 'date', array(
        'label'             => 'form.date_start.label',
        'widget'            => 'single_text',
        'required'          => false,
        'group'             => ['event', 'dates']
    ));

    $builder->add('date_end', 'date', array(
        'label'             => 'form.date_end.label',
        'widget'            => 'single_text',
        'required'          => false,
        'group'             => ['event', 'dates']
    ));

    $builder->add('time_zone', 'alternate_timezone', [
        'label'             => 'form.timezone.label',
        'field_help'        => 'form.timezone.help',
        'empty_value'       => 'form.timezone.empty_value',
        'required'          => false,
        'group'             => ['event', 'dates']
    ]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'label'        => false,
        'compound'     => true,
        'inherit_data' => true
    ]);
}
```

I can't associate errors with my fields. The errors of this form are displayed on the parent's form, not on the field. I saw in the doc, error_bubbling can be false unless the form is compound.

What is the solution with a compound form, to have errors associated with the field ?

Thank you

Comment: I have this issue with a field in my form that is inherited. I can't target the name of the inherited form in my validation routines. The error always bubbles up to the root form. No amount of changing error_bubbling or other settings has worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

With compound forms in Symfony - you can define validation constraints for each entity in the compound relationship and any errors that are produced during validation will be displayed above/near the form elements where the error occurred.

For example - if the form example you posted is bound to the "ExampleEntity" entity - you can define your validation constraints for that entity in your bundle's validation.yml.  Any validation errors will be displayed along side their respective child form - even in collections where validation errors may occur on multiple child forms.

Example src/MyBundle/Resources/Config/validation.yml

```
App\MyBundle\Entity\ExampleEntity:
        properties:
            date_start:
                - NotBlank:
                    message:  Date start cannot be blank.
            date_end:
                - NotBlank:
                    message:  Date end field cannot be blank.
            time_zone:
                - NotBlank:
                    message:  Timezone cannot be blank.
```